# How do I put this code, or similar code in a different class? (VB.NET)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class

This is the code I have so far:

```
Public Class firstForm
    Dim sale(3, 4) As Integer
    Dim numberSellers(3) As Integer
    Dim numberProducts(4) As Integer

Private Sub addButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles addButton.Click


    Dim sellerLineInteger As Integer
    Dim productColumnInteger As Integer

    sellerLineInteger = sellerListBox.SelectedIndex
    productColumnInteger = productListBox.SelectedIndex

    ' add in two dimensional array 
    If sellerLineInteger >= 0 And productColumnInteger >= 0 Then
        sale(sellerLineInteger, productColumnInteger) = Decimal.Parse(saleTextBox.Text)
    End If

    saleTextBox.Clear()
    saleTextBox.Focus()

End Sub
```

I would like to put this code in a different class/form instead. This class would be used to stock the information entered by the user.
I have two list boxes, one button, and one text box. The user pick an item in each list box, enter a number in the text box and then click the button to stock the information.

I tried to implement the code by using another class, but I couldn't get it to work, but it works when I put it like in the code I showed above.

edit: Thanks a lot guys! I'll try this out in a bit.

Comment: Are you trying to separate the code that is inside of addButton_Click? Because if you are, you will probably need to do some sort of binding, instead of using the controls to provide values

Comment: Yes I do, I'm not sure what you mean though.

Comment: With binding you do everything with classes and properties and TIE them to the controls.  With the way you have it written above, you will never be able to separate it into a different class, because the current class is the only one that has sellerListBox, productListBox.. etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im assuming you want to move as much as possible to another class...
if so, heres an example of how you would do that.

your modifed form code looks like:

```
Public Class firstForm

    Dim MyOtherClass As New Class1

    Private Sub addButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles addButton.Click
        MyOtherClass.addItem(sellerListBox, productListBox, saleTextBox)
    End Sub
End Class
```

and the new class would look like this:

```
Public Class Class1
    Private sale(3, 4) As Integer
    Private numberSellers(3) As Integer
    Private numberProducts(4) As Integer




    Public Sub addItem(ByRef my_sellerListBox As ListBox, ByRef my_productListBox As ListBox, ByRef my_saleTextBox As TextBox)
        Dim sellerLineInteger As Integer
        Dim productColumnInteger As Integer

        sellerLineInteger = my_sellerListBox.SelectedIndex
        productColumnInteger = my_productListBox.SelectedIndex

        ' add in two dimensional array 
        If sellerLineInteger >= 0 And productColumnInteger >= 0 Then
            sale(sellerLineInteger, productColumnInteger) = Decimal.Parse(my_saleTextBox.Text)
        End If

        my_saleTextBox.Clear()
        my_saleTextBox.Focus()


    End Sub

End Class
```

note that you must create an instance of the class to use, because it contains data (it cannot be a shared sub)

Comment: note that you infact can separate it into another class, even though that other class does not have direct access to the form objects (listsboxes, testboxes, etc.) in my example, i passed a reference to the listboxes and textbox... you could do the parsing/etc. in the button even handler and then pass integers instead, however. (that is how i would do it - it makes the class more reusable, and helps separate the front end from the back end)

Comment: also, there is no need to add the "my_" prefix to the variable names like i did - they are not duplicated names because they are not in the same scope. i only did it for clariry, to show that you are accessing the passed variables, rather than directly accessing the form variables.

Answer (score 1):

There are different possibilities. I suggest creating two classes for products and sellers

```
Public Class Product
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Sale As Decimal
End Class
```

and

```
Public Class Seller
    Public Property Name As String

    Private _products As New Dictionary(Of String, Product)()
    Public ReadOnly Property Products() As Dictionary(Of String, Product)
        Get
            Return _products
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub SetProductSale(productName As String, sale As Decimal)
        Dim product As Product
        If _products.TryGetValue(productName, product) Then
            product.Sale = sale
        Else
            product = New Product() With { _
                .Name = productName, _
                .Sale = sale _
            }
            _products.Add(productName, product)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function GetProductSale(productName As String) As Decimal
        Dim product As Product
        If _products.TryGetValue(productName, product) Then
            Return product.Sale
        End If
        Return 0D
    End Function
End Class
```

In your form you could then do something like this (I assume that your listboxes store names of sellers and products as strings):

```
Public Class FirstForm
    Private _sellers As New Dictionary(Of String, Seller)()

    Public Sub addButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If sellerListBox.SelectedIndex >= 0 AndAlso _
           productListBox.SelectedIndex >= 0 Then

            Dim sellerName As String = sellerListBox.SelectedItem.ToString()
            Dim productName As String = productListBox.SelectedItem.ToString()

            Dim sale As Decimal
            If [Decimal].TryParse(saleTextBox.Text, sale) Then
                Dim seller As Seller
                If Not _sellers.TryGetValue(sellerName, seller) Then
                    seller = New Seller() With { _
                        .Name = sellerName _
                    }
                    _sellers.Add(sellerName, seller)
                End If

                seller.SetProductSale(productName, sale)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

But you could go one step further and use binding as DJ Burb suggests. The listboxes could be bound directly to lists of sellers and products.

---

As I said, there are different approaches. In this example I store the sale directly within the product and I have copies of each product in each seller. You could also think of a separate sales class combining products and the sale amount. The sellers would then have a sales dictionary instead of a product dictionary. All the products would then be stored in a separate product dictionary. This would allow you to keep unique instances of the products.

Comment: Right.  Then the OP will need to use data binding on the controls.  For the OP, here's an article on data binding http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3665/Data-binding-concepts-in-NET-windows-forms